# Check Date is tomorrow in C#.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I write some code to check that now date is tomorrow :

```
re_dat = SDKClass.Selct_Date_now();  // return today date from database.
DateTime date_now = DateTime.Parse(re_dat).Date;

if (date_now == DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date)
    {
        response.write("tomorrow");
    }
```

but condition doesn't fire.
thanks a lot.

Comment: You are checking if today is tomorrow? Why would that condition ever pass?

Comment: what is the date_now value?

Comment: date_now field is today date

Answer (score 4):

If your question is about difference with some dynamic input date and today date as reference date, then you can use dates difference like this:

> var dateDiff = (DateTime.Today - inputDate.Date).TotalDays;

Here is my simple version of date formatting:

```
public static string GetDateString(DateTime inputDate)
    {
        var dateDiff = (DateTime.Today - inputDate.Date).TotalDays;
        if (dateDiff == 0)
        {
            return "TODAY";
        }
        else if(dateDiff == 1)
        {
            return "YESTERDAY";
        }
        else if(dateDiff == -1)
        {
            return "TOMORROW";
        }
        else
        {
            return inputDate.ToShortDateString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't retrive the today date from database.
i think best solutin for this:

```
if (DateTime.Today == DateTime.Today.AddDays(1))
    {
        Response.Write("Tomorrow");
    }
    else { //Write whatever you want }
```